# Why is `abi.encodePacked` preferred to `bytes` in string comparison?

Tags: solidity, string

[The official documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/types.html#bytes-and-string-as-arrays) recommends to test string equality using

```
keccak256(abi.encodePacked(s1)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(s2))
```

Why is this to be preferred to `keccak256(bytes(s1)) == keccak256(bytes(s2))`?